# XSLT transform failed sometimes

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm not an expert in XSLT and I have an issue that I can't explain with the transformer. This issue occurs only in a production usage : I can't reproduce it myself.

I have a process receiving a XML message (via a JMS queue). This message must be transformed in another XML.

This is the code performing the transforming :

```
final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
final Templates templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xsl));

final Transformer xformer = templates.newTransformer();

try (final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes())) {

    final Source source = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    final Result result = new StreamResult(outputStream);

    xformer.transform(source, result);

    ....
}
```

In the original XML, I receive dates with the format yyyyMMdd (as a String), but I needs them with the format yyyy-MM-dd.

```
<xsl:template match="INVOICE_DATE_FROM">
    <xsl:call-template name="fctFormatDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'dateFrom'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="dateParam">
            <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="fctFormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="elementName"/>
    <xsl:param name="dateParam"/>
    <xsl:if test="$dateParam != '' and $dateParam != '00000000'">
        <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat(concat(concat(substring($dateParam, '1', '4'), '-'), substring($dateParam, number('5'), '2')), '-'), substring($dateParam, number('7'), '2'))"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Most of time, it works and I obtain a well-formatted date. But sometimes, I receive something like that :

```
<dateFrom>IN18-07-01</dateFrom>
```

Someone already met this king of issue ? Or can tell me what it's wrong in this piece of code ?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Just one precision : we use XSLT 1.0

**EDIT 2**

This is a part of the XML (I can't show you more than this, cause of private data an brands products as tag names).

```
<DUNNING_LINE SEGMENT="1">
    <INVOICE_NUMBER>*************</INVOICE_NUMBER>
    <INVOICE_DUE_DATE>20180731</INVOICE_DUE_DATE>
    <INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT>39.49</INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <INVOICE_PAID_AMOUNT>0.00</INVOICE_PAID_AMOUNT>
    <INVOICE_DUE_AMOUNT>39.49</INVOICE_DUE_AMOUNT>
    <INVOICE_DATE_FROM>20180701</INVOICE_DATE_FROM>
    <INVOICE_DATE_TO>20180731</INVOICE_DATE_TO>
    <INVOICE_POSTING_DATE>20180630</INVOICE_POSTING_DATE>
</DUNNING_LINE>
```

Comment: Maybe the language settings in the server are different from those in your test env. That might change the default date and time defaults.

Comment: All the servers are in english. But I don't understand why it can change anything in this case. The origin value is a text (20180701) and the XSLT asks to change it into a formatted text (2018-07-01). Moreover, 99% of the messages a well converted.

Comment: I think the "IN" comes from the origin tag name. I have other cases where I received something like INVO-07-01

Comment: Show us a minimal but complete input XML where that problem occurs and we might be able to tell what is wrong, solely showing the code without the input does't allow anyone to tell what is wrong, other than assuming the input is not in the format you say.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't show you a complete XML because it's containing lots of private data and the structure of the XML is strongly linked to my customer (with some commercial tag names). But this is a sample of tag having the problem : <INVOICE_DATE_FROM>20180701</INVOICE_DATE_FROM> (copy-paste from the XML file)

Comment: It doesn't look like the XSLT is the issue, but whatever is producing the XML. Consider adding a comment to the `xsl:element` code block to allow you to see the raw value. For example `<xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$dateParam" /></xsl:comment>`.

Comment: I added a xs:message if the $dateParam doesn't match ^[0-9]{8}$. I will be able to see those errors in the logs as soon as this version will be deployed in production (seen that I can't reproduce the bug in test env)

Answer (score 1):

Start by simplifying the code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(concat(concat(concat(substring($dateParam, '1', '4'), '-'), substring($dateParam, number('5'), '2')), '-'), substring($dateParam, number('7'), '2'))"/>
```

concat() takes any number of arguments, and the 2nd and 3rd args of substring are numbers, so this reduces to

```
concat(substring($dateParam, 1, 4), '-', 
       substring($dateParam, 5, 2), '-', 
       substring($dateParam, 7, 2))
```

This isn't going to solve your problem, but the first step in debugging code should always be to get rid of unnecessary complexity.

The problem I suspect is that $dateParam already holds the incorrect data, but of course you haven't shown us enough information for me to be able to test this theory.

Comment: Thank you. I already have done this simplification when I started to work on the project (one week ago). But as it's not deployed in production yet, I show you the code as it's in production. What about the input XML, I just added what I can. But when I send exactly the same input in test, there's no error. And in production, I have less than 0.1% of failed process (all the input have the same structure).

Comment: However frustrating it may be, it must surely be clear to you that you haven't provided your readers with enough information to enable them to find this bug.